# Named semaphores in C are not deleted after a signal handler call

Tags: c, signals, semaphore

So the following code is supposed to do the following:

1. The main process creates N_READ number of children processes and then proceeds to print some lines endlessly.
2. The children also print some lines endlessly.
3. When the main process receives a SIGINT signal (CTRL^C from the terminal in this case) he must send a SIGTERM to all his children, wait for them to finish and then delete all the semaphores used.

The use of named semaphores is justified by the fact that this is simulation of the readers-writers problem giving priority to the readers.

However when I end the program and start it again the semaphores have not been deleted, as I get an "semaphore already exists" error and they are in fact in /dev/shm.

P.D. This is college homework and they say global variables are not permitted.

Thank you in advance and here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SEM1 "/example_sem1"
#define SEM2 "/example_sem2"
#define SEM3 "/example_sem3"

#define N_READ 1
#define SECS 0

int  valor_semaforo(sem_t *sem) {
    int sval;

    if (sem_getvalue(sem, &sval) == -1) {
        perror("sem_getvalue");
        sem_unlink(SEM1);
        sem_unlink(SEM2);
        sem_unlink(SEM3);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   return sval;
}

void manejador_SIGINT(int sig) {

    kill(0,SIGTERM);
    while(wait(NULL)>0);
/*xq no llega xq*/
    sem_unlink(SEM1);
    sem_unlink(SEM2);
    sem_unlink(SEM3);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(void) {
    sem_t *sem_write = NULL,*sem_read = NULL,*sem_count = NULL;
    pid_t pid[N_READ];
    int i;
    struct sigaction act;

    sigemptyset(&(act.sa_mask));
    act.sa_flags = 0;

    act.sa_handler = manejador_SIGINT;
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((sem_write = sem_open(SEM1, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1)) == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("sem_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((sem_read = sem_open(SEM2, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1)) == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("sem_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((sem_count = sem_open(SEM3, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0)) == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("sem_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }



    for(i=0;i<N_READ;i++){
        pid[i] = fork();
        if (pid[i] < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (pid[i] == 0) {

            sigemptyset(&(act.sa_mask));
            act.sa_flags = 0;

            act.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
            if (sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL) < 0) {
                perror("sigaction");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            while(1){

                sem_wait(sem_read);
                sem_post(sem_count);
                if(valor_semaforo(sem_count)==1)
                    sem_wait(sem_write);
                sem_post(sem_read);

                printf("R-INI %d\n",getpid());
                fflush(stdout);
                sleep(SECS);
                printf("R-FIN %d\n",getpid());
                fflush(stdout);


                sem_wait(sem_read);
                sem_wait(sem_count);
                if(valor_semaforo(sem_count)==0)
                    sem_post(sem_write);
                sem_post(sem_read);
            }

        }
    }
        while(1){
            sem_wait(sem_write);
            printf("W-INI %d\n",getpid());
            fflush(stdout);
            sleep(SECS);
            printf("W-FIN %d\n",getpid());
            fflush(stdout);
            sem_post(sem_write);
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Doesn’t the SIGTERM terminate the process that should clean up the semaphores?

Comment: Is it an explicit requirement of the assignment that the parent wait for its children to finish before removing the semaphores?  Because it's not a *functional* requirement.  In fact, as otherwise implemented, the parent could unlink the semaphores proactively, as soon as it finishes forking children, without interfering with their and its own use of them.

Comment: It's not safe to call `sem_unlink()` or `exit()` in a signal handler, btw.

Comment: Also, I don't follow your justification for using named semaphores.  The named *vs*. unnamed distinction for semaphores is about how a process *obtains access* to a semaphore, not about how it thereafter uses it.  Your particular implementation takes no advantage whatever of the semaphore names, and would work just as well with process-shared  unnamed semaphores.  And with unnamed semaphores, you wouldn't need to take any cleanup steps, and different runs of the program would not interfere with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jonathan said, the SIGTERM signal I use does terminate the process that should clean up the semaphores. By ignoring the signal in the parent process, everything works well.